# QGIS find connected lines and store them as Attribute

Tags: qgis, shapefile, routing

I have the following issue and as I'm quite a QGIS beginner I don't know how to solve it.
I have several Shape files that contain multisection lines.
The all have an attribute called "ID".
What I want to have is a Table or an additional attribute that shows me, what line(s) with what "ID" are connected to this line.
So here an example:
[image]

The result should look like this:

[image]

Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can try this `array_to_string(overlay_touches(@layer, expression:="ID"))` see for more details : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-touches